# Censored likelihood function in R returning -Inf or NaN

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I have an original likelihood for the distribution of network sizes, $y$, conditioned on the number of combined networks, $n$, under negative binomial parameters mean $R$ and dispersion $k$:

> $L(R,k|y,n)=\prod_{y}\prod_{n}P(Y=y|n)^y$

Some of my data are censored, so I need to extend the likelihood to $a_{yn}$ fully observed (uncensored) networks of size $y$ with $n$ combined networks and $b_{yn}$ censored networks of *at least* size $y$ with $n$ combined networks:

> $L(R,k|\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b})=\prod_{y}\prod_{n}P(Y=y|n)^{a_{yn}}P(Y≥y|n)^{b_{yn}}$

Where $P(Y=y|n)$ is the probability of a network size conditioned on the number of combined networks, and $P(Y≥y|n)=1-\sum_{i=1}^{y-1}P(Y=y_i|n)$.

The original (uncensored) data are a two column matrix with the first column as the $y$ values and the second column as the $n$ conditioned values (if $n=1$ then it is not a combined cluster, if $n=2$ then it is two combined clusters with $y=y_{n_1}+y_{n_2}$, and so on). To calculate the log-likelihood for a given $R$ and $k$ value in R software was fairly straight forward:

```r
 original_likelihood <- function(Y,R,k) {
  y <- Y[,1]
  n <- Y[,2]
  logpyn <- log(n)-log(y)+lgamma(k*y+y-n)-(lgamma(k*y)+lgamma(y-n+1))+(y-n)*log(R/k)-(k*y+y-n)*log(1+R/k)
  return(sum(logpyn))
}
```

This works fine with no issues. However, adding in the censoring is a challenge for me.

Now the data are a three column matrix, with different processes needed depending on the censor status (the third column being the censoring status of 0=uncensored and 1=censored).

Below is my attempt - and sample data to show it works reasonably well but with certain value/parameter combinations (i.e. a large network with exceedingly low mean), it results in `-Inf` or `NaN`. This prevents optimization of the likelihood/MLE.

I am not sure if this is due to an incorrect implementation of the math, or if it is a coding issue (the coding may be completely wrong). Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
new_likelihood <- function(Y,R,k) {
  p_function <- function(y,n){ #Create a dummy function to apply in loop
     exp(log(n)-log(y)+lgamma(k*y+y-n)-(lgamma(k*y)+lgamma(y-n+1))+(y-n)*log(R/k)-(k*y+y-n)*log(1+R/k))
    }
  liks_a <- numeric(nrow(Y)) # initialize vector of logliks for `a` clusters
  liks_b <- numeric(nrow(Y)) # initialize vector of logliks for `b` clusters

  #Loop through each row of the data
  for(i in 1:nrow(Y)){
    y <- Y[i,1]
    n <- Y[i,2]
    c <- Y[i,3]

      if (c==0){ #For uncensored, apply regular PDF
        liks_a[i] <- log(p_function(y,n))
      } 

      if(c==1){ #for censored, sum to do 1-(sum(Y-1))
        liks_b[i] <- log(1-sum(p_function(1:(y-1),n)))
      } 
  }
  sumliks <- sum(liks_a,liks_b)
  return(sumliks)
}
```

Below is some sample data and functions to show the issue:

```
#data are three column matrix for 1) y values, 2) n values, 3) censorship status
test0 <- cbind(c(1,1,3,5,1000),c(1,1,1,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,0))
test1 <- cbind(c(1,1,3,5,1000),c(1,1,1,1,1),c(0,0,1,0,1))

R <- 0.9; k <- 0.25
R_lo <- 0.02

#Reasonable R values work fine
original_likelihood(test0, R, k) # Original pdf 
new_likelihood(test0, R, k)      # New pdf but should return same as above (no censoring)
new_likelihood(test1, R, k)      # Should return higher value

#Issue when creating a likelihood surface with exceedingly low ranges of R and k
original_likelihood(test0, R_lo, k) # Retuns numerical result 
new_likelihood(test0, R_lo, k)      # Returns -Inf
new_likelihood(test1, R_lo, k)      # Returns -Inf
```

Based on comments, below is my optimization code, and code to generate simulated data that could be used:

```
##' Calculate likelihood surface
##' @param simdata is a 2 column matrix of Y an n values
##' @param Rrange is a vector of R values for the surface (typically 0.05-1.05 by 0.01)
##' @param krange is a vector of k values for the surface (typically 0.04-25 by 0.01, followed by 55 to represent infinity)
##' @param k_only is only for the k estimates/k profile likelihood 

surflike_yn<- function(simdata, Rrange, krange, k_only=FALSE){
  if (k_only==TRUE){
    Rrange_2 <- 1-(mean(simdata[,2])/mean(simdata[,1])) #R MLE value is 1-(E(n)/E(y))
  } else {Rrange_2 <- Rrange}
  likesurf <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(Rrange_2),length(krange))
  for(i in 1:length(Rrange_2)){
    for(j in 1:length(krange)){
      likesurf[i,j] <- new_likelihood(simdata,Rrange_2[i],krange[j])
    }
  }
  return(likesurf)
}

surfests_yn<-function(likesurf, conf.interval=95, k_only=FALSE){
  chiV<-qchisq(conf.interval/100, df=1)/2 
  profprep_k <- apply(likesurf,2,function(x){max(x)})
  profprep_k2 <- krange[profprep_k-max(profprep_k)>-chiV]
  profprep_R <- apply(likesurf,1,function(x){max(x)})
  profprep_R2 <- Rrange[profprep_R-max(profprep_R)>-chiV]

  likesurf_max <- likesurf==max(likesurf)

  output <- matrix(NA,2,3)
  output[1,1] <- Rrange[sum(seq(1,length(Rrange))%*%likesurf_max)] #k point estimate
  output[1,2] <- min(profprep_R2) #k lower CI
  output[1,3] <- max(profprep_R2) #k upper CI
  output[2,1] <- krange[sum(likesurf_max%*%seq(1,length(krange)))] #R point estimate
  output[2,2] <- min(profprep_k2) #R lower CI
  output[2,3] <- ifelse(max(profprep_k2)==max(krange),Inf,max(profprep_k2)) #R upper CI
  colnames(output) <- c("point_est","lower_ci","upper_ci"); rownames(output) <- c("R_hat","k_hat") 
  if (k_only==TRUE) {
    output <- output[2,]
  }
  return(output)
}
```

Below are functions to simulate network data and randomly censor some of the networks:

```
#Branching process function
bp <- function(gens=20, init.size=1, offspring, ...){  
  Z <- list() #initiate the list
  Z[[1]] <- init.size #set the first position of the list as the number of index cases
  i <- 1 
  while(sum(Z[[i]]) > 0 && i <= gens) { 
    Z[[i+1]] <- offspring(sum(Z[[i]]), ...) 
    i <- i+1 
  } 
  return(Z)
}
##' ___________________
##' Censoring Function
##' ___________________
##' 
##' @param z is the original branching process nested list data
##' @param perc is the percent of clusters to be censored
##'             Note: since only censors Y≥2, not the percent of all clusters censored
##' - - - - - - - 

censor_z <- function(z, perc=0.2){
  z.cen <- z;                                 
  for (i in 1:length(z)){                    
    if (length(z[[i]])>3) {                  
      if(runif(1)<=perc){                 
        if(length(z[[i]])==4){
          n <- 4} else {
          n <- sample(4:length(z[[i]]),1)}    
        z.cen[[i]][n:length(z[[i]])] <- NA    
      }}}
  out_list <- lapply(z.cen, function(x) {     
    inds <- sapply(x, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
    if(any(inds)) x[seq_len(which.max(inds) - 1)] else x})

  j1 <- out_list                             
  for (i in 1:length(j1)){
    j1[[i]][[1]]<-NULL
  }
  j2<-numeric(length(j1))
  for (k in 1:length(j1)){
    j2[k]<-sum(lengths(j1[[k]]))
  }
  y.cens <- j2
  y.true <- unlist(lapply(z,function(x) sum(unlist(x)))) 

  censclust <- rep(0,times=length(z.cen))     
  for (i in 1:length(z.cen)){
    if(any(is.na(z.cen[[i]]))){
      censclust[i] <- 1
    }}
  cens <- data.frame(y.true,y.cens,censclust)
  return(cens)
}

##' Simulate data
##' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

# Create sample data
z <- replicate(1000,bp(offspring=rnbinom, mu=0.9, size=0.25))
z_cens <- censor_z(z)
final_data <- cbind(z_cens[,2],rep(1,length(z_cens[,2])),z_cens[,3]) 
#ranges
Rrange <- seq(0.05,1.05,by=0.01)
krange <- c(seq(0.04,25,by=0.01),55)
```

Comment: You get `-Inf` when `sum(p_function(1:(y-1),n))` returns the value 1.  For your examples with `k <- 0.25` this happens whenever `R_lo` < 0.5.  But why is your optimization code (which you don't show) even looking at such a value because the log likelihood (and therefore the likelihood) is as low as you can go?  I think you'd also need to present your optimization code.  Maybe it's your starting values are too far away from final maximum likelihood values?

Comment: Hi @JimB - Thank you - I have added both the optimization functions and the functions to simulate meaningful sample data to optimize. I first calculate a likelihood surface then use the to simultaneously find the MLE of R and k and their confidence intervals, which is why the "search" range is so wide

Answer (score 1):

Showing your optimization code would be helpful as that process should steer clear of unlikely values.  For your example with `test1`, the log likelihood surface looks like the following:

[image: Log likelihood surface]

You were examining `R = 0.02` and `k = 0.25` (the point in red) which is far away from the maximum likelihood solution.  So if your starting values are around `R = 1.5` and `k = 1.5`, your code should find the maximum likelihood estimates (the green point) and not go near the troubled waters.

**Update**

Given your additional code (for both data generation and optimization) I wonder why you aren't using `optim`.  Also, you're getting `NaN`'s and `-Inf` because machine precision just doesn't keep enough significant digits and the code attempts to take the log of zero.  But that really only happens (in this case) when the likelihood is near zero and only because your optimization routine goes out and searches such "unlikely" parameter values.

Here is a modification of your code that finds the maximum likelihood estimates along the the usual asymptotic estimates of standard error and approximate 95% confidence intervals.

```
# Create sample data
z <- replicate(1000,bp(offspring=rnbinom, mu=0.9, size=0.25))
z_cens <- censor_z(z)
final_data <- cbind(z_cens[,2],rep(1,length(z_cens[,2])),z_cens[,3]) 

# Redefine new_likelihood into a form that optim likes
  logL <- function(p, Y) {new_likelihood(Y, p[1], p[2])}

# Find maximum likelihood estimates
  results <- optim(c(1, 0.5), logL, Y=final_data, control=list(fnscale=-1),
    hessian=TRUE)

# Maximum likelihood estimates
  (Rhat <- results$par[1])
#[1] 0.9125802
  (khat <- results$par[2])
#[1] 0.2343493

# Covariance matrix
  (covmat <- -solve(results$hessian))
#              [,1]          [,2]
#[1,]  5.823526e-04 -4.877741e-05
#[2,] -4.877741e-05  7.062894e-04

# Standard errors
  (R.se <- covmat[1,1]^0.5)
#[1] 0.02413198
  (k.se <- covmat[2,2]^0.5)
#[1] 0.02657611

# Approximate 95% confidence intervals
  (R.95Lower <- max(0, Rhat - 1.96*R.se))
#[1] 0.8652815
  (R.95Upper <- Rhat + 1.96*R.se)
#[1] 0.9598789
  (k.95Lower <- max(0, khat - 1.96*k.se))
#[1] 0.1822602
  (k.95Upper <- khat + 1.96*k.se)
#[1] 0.2864385
```

You'll notice that there are no warnings about `NaN`'s.  That's because the starting values (1 and 0.5) are close enough to the final maximum likelihood estimates.  Had I used 1 and 1 for the starting values, then I would have obtained warnings.  That just a fact of life for iterative procedures:  good starting values are worth their weight in gold.

Comment: Thank you! I have added both my optimization code and code to generate data more similar to my actual data (i.e simulate 1000 networks instead of the 5 in the test example). One of the reasons the values I was examining were so low is because the code simultaneously calculates the MLE and confidence intervals for R and k (the "search" ranges for these parameters didn't pose an issue using the `original_likelihood` function). Thank you again for your support!